# Serve view of directory's most recent files only

Tags: filesystems, mount, fuse, file-sharing, filter

I have a directory with ~100k files that loads very slowly over the internet through most protocols (just listing the directory can time out). I'd like to speed things up by only showing files from the last 6 months.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know there are a few FUSE-based filesystems able to filter by filename (eg rofs-filtered), but I haven't found one that can filter by date. The goal is to serve the directory through a HTTP file server like dockerized Nextcloud or File Browser, while being able to view the full directory on LAN in conditions when it's fast enough.

I've checked https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Filesystems

I've thought about a union mount of two directories (one with old files and one with new files), with a script on CRON to move the files periodically, but this is a round-about way with added complexity.

Comment: Have you considered organising your files in subdirectories, maybe based on some timestamp?

Comment: @Kusalananda A lot of legacy apps are configured to save and read files in the bulk directory, so it would be very challenging to reorganize. Also timestamps can be updated, causing confusion about where a file is if it's not dynamically moved